# Android emulator doesn't start running

Tags: flutter, dart, android-emulator

Upon clicking on "Open Android Emulator: Nexus 6 API", it gives me the error at the bottom right. It also doesn't work with other devices and I  don't see any error upon opening the folder mentioned.
[android-studio](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6FR4O.png)
Here is the log from idea.log:

```
2023-12-24 15:00:25,853 [1426702]   INFO - #com.android.build.diagnostic.WindowsDefenderCheckService - Suppress warning for the project clicked
2023-12-24 15:00:25,854 [1426703]   INFO - #com.android.build.diagnostic.WindowsDefenderCheckService - Suppressing check, globally=false
2023-12-24 15:01:03,835 [1464684]   INFO - #io.flutter.run.daemon.DeviceDaemon - shutting down Flutter device daemon #2: C:/Users/ZEN/Desktop/Programming/Flutter/flutter_windows_3.16.4-stable/flutter/bin/flutter.bat daemon
2023-12-24 15:01:07,329 [1468178]   INFO - #c.i.o.a.i.PopupMenuPreloader - 27099 ms since showing to preload popup menu 'Project View Popup Menu' at 'ProjectViewPopup(preload-bgt)' in 17 ms
2023-12-24 15:01:07,943 [1468792]   INFO - #io.flutter.run.daemon.DeviceDaemon - starting Flutter device daemon #3: C:/Users/ZEN/Desktop/Programming/Flutter/flutter_windows_3.16.4-stable/flutter/bin/flutter.bat daemon
2023-12-24 15:01:09,505 [1470354]   INFO - #io.flutter.run.daemon.DeviceDaemon - flutter device daemon #3: Starting device daemon...
2023-12-24 15:01:10,222 [1471071]   INFO - #c.i.w.i.i.j.s.JpsGlobalModelSynchronizerImpl - Saving global entities to files
2023-12-24 15:01:24,321 [1485170]   INFO - #c.i.w.i.i.j.s.JpsGlobalModelSynchronizerImpl - Saving global entities to files
2023-12-24 15:01:24,359 [1485208]   INFO - #c.i.c.ComponentStoreImpl - Saving appXDebuggerSettings took 17 ms
2023-12-24 15:03:17,084 [1597933]   INFO - #c.i.w.i.i.j.s.JpsGlobalModelSynchronizerImpl - Saving global entities to files
2023-12-24 15:03:17,209 [1598058]   INFO - #c.i.c.ComponentStoreImpl - Saving Project(name=pliion, containerState=COMPONENT_CREATED, componentStore=C:\Users\ZEN\StudioProjects\pliion)Kotlin2JvmCompilerArguments took 28 ms
2023-12-24 15:04:50,912 [1691761]   INFO - #c.i.w.i.i.j.s.JpsGlobalModelSynchronizerImpl - Saving global entities to files
2023-12-24 15:04:54,550 [1695399]   WARN - #com.android.sdklib.deviceprovisioner.LocalEmulatorProvisionerPlugin - Emulator failed to connect within 5 minutes
2023-12-24 15:06:03,367 [1764216]   INFO - #c.i.w.i.i.j.s.JpsGlobalModelSynchronizerImpl - Saving global entities to files
2023-12-24 15:06:13,863 [1774712]   INFO - #c.i.w.i.i.j.s.JpsGlobalModelSynchronizerImpl - Saving global entities to files
2023-12-24 15:06:26,592 [1787441]   INFO - #c.i.w.i.i.j.s.JpsGlobalModelSynchronizerImpl - Saving global entities to files
2023-12-24 15:06:47,113 [1807962]   INFO - #c.i.w.i.i.j.s.JpsGlobalModelSynchronizerImpl - Saving global entities to files
2023-12-24 15:06:57,416 [1818265]   INFO - #c.i.w.i.i.j.s.JpsGlobalModelSynchronizerImpl - Saving global entities to files
2023-12-24 15:07:03,707 [1824556]   INFO - #c.i.w.i.i.j.s.JpsGlobalModelSynchronizerImpl - Saving global entities to files
2023-12-24 15:07:16,052 [1836901]   INFO - #c.i.w.i.i.j.s.JpsGlobalModelSynchronizerImpl - Saving global entities to files
2023-12-24 15:07:20,528 [1841377]   INFO - #c.i.w.i.i.j.s.JpsGlobalModelSynchronizerImpl - Saving global entities to files
2023-12-24 15:07:35,794 [1856643]   INFO - #c.i.w.i.i.j.s.JpsGlobalModelSynchronizerImpl - Saving global entities to files
2023-12-24 15:07:39,921 [1860770]   INFO - #c.i.w.i.i.j.s.JpsGlobalModelSynchronizerImpl - Saving global entities to files
2023-12-24 15:07:42,723 [1863572]   INFO - #c.i.w.i.i.j.s.JpsGlobalModelSynchronizerImpl - Saving global entities to files
2023-12-24 15:09:41,689 [1982538]   INFO - #c.i.w.i.i.j.s.JpsGlobalModelSynchronizerImpl - Saving global entities to files
2023-12-24 15:10:06,969 [2007818]   INFO - #c.i.w.i.i.j.s.JpsGlobalModelSynchronizerImpl - Saving global entities to files
```

After clicking on the "run" button in the device manager, it just shows that it loading for 5 minutes and terminates then(but no device appears)

It works when I select windows as the target device though.

Comment: Have you tried staring it manually ? Make sure API 34 sdk is installed. Recreate device in emulator. Try Updating android studio if not.

Comment: API 34 sdk is installed, starting it manually doesnt work. I updated flutter and android studio is already updated, but nothing changed.  Also, when I click the plus sign on the running devices tab, it shows 'Unable to launch Nexus 6 API 34 - The emulator process for AVD Nexus_6_API_34 has terminated.'